# How "unless" and "until" affect the structure and meaning of a complex sentence

Tags: meaning, syntactic-analysis, till-until, unless

Here is an ex­cerpt from a book I’m read­ing:

> **Un­less** con­sumed in highly skilled rit­ual con­texts, as is prac­ticed
>   in many tra­di­tional so­ci­eties, what drugs in fact do is re­duce our
>   per­cep­tion of both what can be ac­com­plished and what we as in­di­vid­u­als
>   are able to ac­com­plish, **un­til** the two are in bal­ance. This is a
>   pleas­ant state of af­fairs, but it is only a mis­lead­ing sim­u­la­tion of
>   that en­joy­ment that comes from in­creas­ing op­por­tu­ni­ties for ac­tions
>   and the abil­i­ties to act.

Can any­body help me to in­ter­pret these lines, as the us­age of *un­less* and *un­til* seems quite com­plex?

Comment: The entire passage is overly complex. I don't think the problem has anything to do with either *unless* or *until*. Does the following make sense? *Unless you are told otherwise, keep exercising until you are tired.* If it does, then you know what those words mean. Your problem isn't with them, but with parsing everything else.

Comment: Have you looked up "unless" and "until" in a dictionary?

Comment: (But I agree that the paragraph is gobbledygook.  I suspect it was written to intentionally obfuscate it's claims.)

Comment: What drugs do (except when con­sumed in highly skilled rit­ual con­texts) is to re­duce  both 1.) our per­cep­tion of what can be ac­com­plished and 2.) our per­cep­tion of what we as in­di­vid­u­als are able to ac­com­plish. Drugs reduce  1.) and 2.) until 1.) and 2.) are in balance. This is a state which people find pleasant, but it is only a simulation of the real enjoyment that comes from having the opportunity and ability to actually do something.

Comment: @Shoe What does until mean here sir? Does it mean that the perception is reduced till 1.) and 2.) are in balance?

Comment: I take it to mean that drugs reduce both of these perceptions to the point that they are in balance or equal. I don't think the idea is particularly well-expressed by the author, and don't really understand how this balance can be considered pleasant. Maybe someone who knows more about Csikszentmihalyi's work can explain. Perhaps you should ask the question on the Psychology site.

Comment: "Unless" here roughly means "there is an exception to the rule", followed by the exception (ritual context). After the exception, they state what they see as the rule for how drugs affect people.

"Until" is pretty separate from "unless" in this paragraph. The author states that two perceptions (what _can_ be done and what we _think_ we can do) are both reduced, and that at some point, they become equal.

Answer (score 1):

Original text:

> Un­less con­sumed in highly skilled rit­ual con­texts, as is prac­ticed in many tra­di­tional so­ci­eties, what drugs in fact do is re­duce our per­cep­tion of both what can be ac­com­plished and what we as in­di­vid­u­als are able to ac­com­plish, un­til the two are in bal­ance. This is a pleas­ant state of af­fairs, but it is only a mis­lead­ing sim­u­la­tion of that en­joy­ment that comes from in­creas­ing op­por­tu­ni­ties for ac­tions and the abil­i­ties to act.

My interpretation:

> What drugs in fact [normally] do is re­duce our per­cep­tion of **both** ... :
>   (1) what [theoretically] can be ac­com­plished; and also
>   (2) what *we as in­di­vid­u­als* are [actually] able to ac­com­plish
>   until [our per­cep­tion of item (1) above & our per­cep­tion of item (2) above] are in balance [with one another].
>   [That can seem to be] a pleas­ant state of af­fairs, ...
>   but [in reality] it is only a mis­lead­ing sim­u­la­tion of [the] en­joy­ment that comes from [what seems like]
>   (1) in­creas­ing op­por­tu­ni­ties for ac­tions, and
>   (2) the abil­i­ties to act.
>
> [Unless ...] The only occasions when drugs do not have that effect is when they are "con­sumed in highly skilled rit­ual con­texts" [such as the rituals] prac­ticed in many tra­di­tional so­ci­eties.

Comment: Sir, until does seem ambiguous here. Until 1 and 2 balance each other out is not clear. Please help to clear this.

Comment: Does until mean that both the perceptions are reduced till both are in balance.

Comment: I've made some revisions to my answer - does that help?

Comment: It seems like the author is implying that the two reduced perceptions being in balance is what leads to "a pleasant state of affairs" in the next sentence.